# Java String comparison wrong outcome

Tags: java, android, string, comparison

I am trying to get a Save button to enable/disable based on if the EditTexts actually change, but my string comparison is not working at all.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    String newSet = editable.toString();

    newSet = newSet.trim();
    if(!newSet.equals(ip) || !newSet.equals(port) || !newSet.equals(username) || !newSet.equals(password)){
        saveButton.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

It keeps telling me the strings are different even though they aren't. Even when I print it out I get exactly the same String back.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This is a perfect LOL question...:P

Comment: You need to read and internalize this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it like that, way easier to read :

```
if (!Arrays.asList(ip, port, username, password).contains(newSet))
{
    saveButton.setEnabled(true);
}
else
{
    saveButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Or :

```
saveButton.setEnabled(!Arrays.asList(ip, port, username, password).contains(newSet));
```

Comment: Ah I was trying something like that, didn't think of using a list though. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Probably you want `&&` instead of `||`:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
  String newSet = editable.toString().trim();

  saveButton.setEnabled(!newSet.equals(ip) && 
                        !newSet.equals(port) && 
                        !newSet.equals(username) && 
                        !newSet.equals(password)); 
}
```

enable `saveButton` if `newSet` *is not a* ip, port, username or password

Answer (score 2):

`newSet` can't be equal to all four of these Strings, unless all 4 are equal to each other. Therefore the condition will most likely return false.

If you require that `newSet` be equal to either one of those 4 Strings, the correct condition would be :

```
if(!(newSet.equals(ip) || newSet.equals(port) || newSet.equals(username) || newSet.equals(password)))
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `||` with `&&`

```
if(!newSet.equals(ip) && !newSet.equals(port) && !newSet.equals(username) && !newSet.equals(password))
```

Reason :

`OR(||)`   **If any** condition get satisfied it will enter inside the loop.
`AND(&&)`  **If all** conditions get satisfied then and then only it will enter inside the loop.

In your case you need to satisfy all the conditions, that's why use and operator instead of or operator.